# How to host two web servers on same network under the same domain

Tags: domains, web-hosting, subdomain, reverse-proxy, vpn

I have multiple Raspberry Pi's on my network that are hosting different web apps that all run webservers (OwnCloud, VPN, Webpage).

I was wondering what the best way to have them under a single domain or sub domains. Should I just use Ngnix as a reverse proxy or is there another option?

Comment: If your router does not allow HTTP filter rules that can modify request headers and route internally, most off the shelf routers do not, then creating a proxy is the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple options, but a small webserver you control that handles your domain and being a reverse proxy for all your backend services seem the easiest solution.